# decomposing number created by a formula

Tags: c#

I have a "formula" to build a number that is this: `parameter + ( 256 * i )` where `i` represents numbers from 0 to 10.

If `i = 0` I get the naked `parameter` value, thats no problem. The problem is that I don't know how to even find out if the `i` variable was 0 or have any other value.

For example, if I receive value 786, I know that this means: `274 + (256 * 2)` but ow can I make a code to find out if I gave it any value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 256 = 2^8, it means if `parameter` is always less than 256, `parameter` is the least significant 8 bits (`parameter = v & 255`) and `i` is the rest of the bits (`i = v >> 8`).

If `parameter` can be greater than 256, it's not possible to find out in general whether `i` was 0 or not, if you don't already have `i`. (In your example, how do you know it's not `18 + 256 * 3`?)

Comment: Well, in fact I only need to find out the `parameter` value. I did the following logics. If I receive a number, I `>> 8` it, and then I get the value I received, and subtract `256 * result` and then I get the original `parameter` value. My values are greater than 256 but my code worked... Im not getting any problem so far I think.